# get displayname and office from samaccountname export to csv

Tags: powershell

How I can get the `displayname` and the office from a `samaccountname` list (.txt)? After that I want to save the `displaynames` and the offices to a .csv file. Here is a approach:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\TMP\test.txt
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=$user)" -Property name, office | Select-Object -Property Name, Office

}
```

It should look like:

[image]

Hope you can help me?

Comment: You should add the following pipeline: `| Export-Csv  -Path <PATH> -NoTypeInformation` (Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

Comment: it does not works, it outputs only the first displayname and office and both in the same row...

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the `Export-CSV` command but from your comments you might be having issues with placement or your construct of `foreach`.

Lets try this then

```powershell
$users = Get-Content C:\TMP\test.txt
$users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=$_)" -Property name,office | Select-Object -Property Name,office
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Update from comments**

Was having issues understanding your output from the comments which was why I wanted more that just a picture of the headers. I don't an issue with this code and the text should be quoted so special characters, like commas, should not be an issue. Please update you question with the text content of a sample file *and* your PowerShell version in case that is coming into play.

Comment: It works, but is there a way to fill the Offices in Row B like in the picture above?

Comment: Ah... didnt notice the issue at first. In AD Office is actually `physicalDeliveryOfficeName`

Comment: at this moment the output looks: Max, Mustermann,"Room 1" both in row A but i want Row A: Max, Mustermann and Row B: "Room 1" like here in the picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NmF1l.png

Comment: No, your code was right, but i want in Row A in excel the Name and in Row B the Office. You know?

Answer (score 0):

Use the delimiter parameter at the end

```
$users = Get-Content C:\TMP\test.txt
$users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=$_)" -Property name,office | Select-Object -Property Name,office
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\export.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```